# Windows 7 64bit Bash "heroku: command not found"

Tags: git-bash, heroku-cli

I'm trying to get the `heroku-cli` working via Git Bash, but have been struggling for a few days. Initially an install of `railsinstaller` installed the older heroku toolbelt which I have since uninstalled. When I ran heroku before uninstalling it I received the message `This is the legacy Heroku CLI`

I have downloaded the latest install for windows x64, installed it, restarted windows, checked paths but its still not working. When I run `heroku --version`, I get the error `command not found`.
I've checked the paths and they look correct as per the attached screenshot.

I'm all out of ideas, any suggestions on how to get it to work?

[image]

Comment: Please copy/paste instead of posting screenshots

Answer (score 3):

So after uninstalling and reinstalling I found the issue, and it had nothing to do with the install.

It seems that when you run in either windows cmd window or git cmd the code `heroku --version` works, however when using Git Bash, I had to use the full file name i.e.:

```
heroku.cmd --version
```

So including the .cmd fixed it, I'm not sure if its supposed to be like that,but at least it's working for me now.

Answer (score -1):

Try this on hyper

```
$ npm install -g heroku
```

(after it has installed)

```
$ heroku login
```